# Analytic function with assigned 2n imaginary points on unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

f(z) is analytic in a domain containing the closed disk $|z|\le1$.
f(z) is non zero on the circle $|z|=1$ and on $|z|=1$
there are exactly 2n different points where $Re(f(z)) =0$.
Show that f(z) has  at most n zeros in $|z|\lt1$.

The only lead I have in mind is the argument principle but I am not quite sure how to use it as there are no details regarding the imaginary points.

Comment: You could assume the contrary.

Comment: The number of zeros is the number of times $f$ winds the unit circle around $0.$ For each such winding, the curve has to intersect the imaginary axis at least twice. Since the latter number is $2n$ we can only orbit $0$ $n$ times. That is the first thing that comes to mind, but it's just an intuitive sketch

Comment: ok but then we need to have the points split between Im >0 and Im < 0.

Comment: @zhw Couldn't - theoretically - the winding number of $f$ (when $z$ runs through $\mathbb T$) be $n+1$, where, say, the curve starts somewhere in the upper halfplane, makes a small loop (not intersecting $\mathbb R$) and then $n$ large loops (each time intersecting $\mathbb R$ twice)?

Comment: I meant the right half plane and $i\mathbb R$ instead of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Friedrich Philipp: interesting and then maybe go back to the original question with some symmetry principle.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp No, a loop in the open right half plane does not wind around $0.$

Comment: @zhw. Why is that necessary? Aren't there analytic functions mapping the unit disc to, say, $\{\operatorname{Re}(z)> 1\}$? I am not asking because I know. Just being naive...

Comment: Of course there are. But those have no zeros. We're not counting how many times f wraps the circle around all points, we're trying to count how many times f wraps the circle around 0

Comment: @zhw. Do we? Couldn't $f$ map the unit circle to the circle around $1+i$ with radius one and running through it $2n$ times? $f(z) = 1+i + z^{2n}$ would do that...

Comment: You could, sure. What is your point though? Could you reread my first comment again and tell me what is bothering you about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of zeros of $f$ inside the unit circle equals

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z},$$

where $\gamma (t) = f(e^{it}), 0\le t \le 2\pi.$ So we're done if we show the imaginary part of the above integral is $\le 2n\pi.$

Lemma: Suppose $\alpha : [a,b]\to \mathbb C$ is a contour in the closed right half plane such that $\alpha(a), \alpha (b) \in i\mathbb R,$ and $\alpha(t) \ne 0$ for all $t.$ Then

$$\tag 1\text { Im }\int_\alpha \frac{dz}{z} \in \{-\pi, 0 ,\pi\}.$$

The same result holds if the left half plane is used in place of the right half plane.

Proof: We know $\log z,$ the principal value $\log,$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty,0]$ and satisfies $\log'(z) = 1/z$ there. Thus the integral in $(1)$ equals

$$\tag 2 \log \alpha (b) - \log \alpha (a).$$

Now $\arg \alpha(a), \arg \alpha (b) \in \{-\pi/2, \pi/2\},$ so the imaginary part of $(2)$ must lie in $\{-\pi, 0 ,\pi\}.$

For the left half plane we can choose a different branch of $\log,$ or simply apply the above to $-\alpha,$ the reflection of $\alpha $ about $0.$

Back to our problem: The hypotheses show that $\gamma (t)=f(e^{it})$ breaks neatly into $2n$ subcontours $\alpha_k,$ each of which satisfies the hypotheses in the lemma. Thus

$$ \int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z} = \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \int_{\alpha_k} \frac{dz}{z},$$

and the imaginary part of the right side is $\le 2n \pi$ by the lemma. As observed earlier, this gives us the result.